# Python weekday drop from DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

I try to drop the weekdays from a dataframe (financial time series) and I keep getting the following error:

```
"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'weekday'"
```

Here is my code:

```
df = df[df.date.weekday()  < 5]
df = df.drop(df.date.weekday() < 5)
```

I tried a few others but nothing seemed to work.

I looked at dtypes and this is what I get:

```
Unnamed: 0           int64
close              float32
date                object
high               float64
low                float64
open               float64
quoteVolume        float64
volume             float64
weightedAverage    float64
dtype: object
```

So date is an object, but I can't transform it to datetime, I tried these:

```
df['date'] = df.date.astype('date')
df['date'] = df.date.astype('datetime')
```

both gave me the error:

```
TypeError: data type "date" not understood
```

The time format of the Series is: `2016-09-23 17:00:00` so `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: okey I converted it to datetime with datetime64[ns] ... I read up on this type soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.weekday < 5]
```

Comment: the dt.weekday is df.weekday right? Edit: Nope its not it works with .dt.weekday, some more reading to mee then about this

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.date)` returns a Series of `datetime` type, `dt` is used so that you can get the `weekday` from the Series. You can't use `weekday` directly on the *Series*. It will error out.

Comment: So like dt contains the 0-6 index of the weekdays?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html), it is an accessor to access different attributes from datetime objects, such as days, month, year, hour etc. *weekdays* is one of the attributes you can access via `dt`.